# compile errors after adding qt libs

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

adding QtNetwork lib to project is not setting linking paths `target_link_library(<target_name> Qt5::Network)`

blow provided definitions

```
add_definitions(-std=c++1z -DEIGEN_STACK_ALLOCATION_LIMIT=0 -DEIGEN_DEFAULT_TO_ROW_MAJOR -O3)

target_link_library(<target_name> Qt5::Network)
```

Comment: "I am getting a bunch of compile errors." is not a problem description with which we can help you. Show **exact** error messages (at least, the first ones). See also [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: for example  `error: ‘integer_sequence’ is not a member of ‘std’`

it seems that after adding link_library some env variables are changed

Comment: Please, add to the **question post** the **complete error message**. It should include a name of the file where the error arises, a line number, and an inclusion sequence if the error found in the header file.

Comment: Im not sure what `std=c++1z` means exactly (is it c++11?), but `std::integer_sequence` is a c++14 feature.

Comment: std=c++1z is c++17

Comment: I am thinking maybe there should be some flags or cmake policies to apply on project

Comment: I think the command you're looking for is [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html), not `target_linklibrary()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding the global CMake CXX flag:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```